# How to remove leading and trailing zeros in a string? Python

Tags: python, string, trailing, chomp, leading-zero

I have several alphanumeric strings like these

```
listOfNum = ['000231512-n','1209123100000-n00000','alphanumeric0000', '000alphanumeric']
```

The desired output for removing **trailing** zeros would be:

```
listOfNum = ['000231512-n','1209123100000-n','alphanumeric', '000alphanumeric']
```

The desired output for **leading** trailing zeros would be:

```
listOfNum = ['231512-n','1209123100000-n00000','alphanumeric0000', 'alphanumeric']
```

The desire output for removing both leading and trailing zeros would be:

```
listOfNum = ['231512-n','1209123100000-n', 'alphanumeric', 'alphanumeric']
```

For now i've been doing it the following way, please suggest a better way if there is:

```
listOfNum = ['000231512-n','1209123100000-n00000','alphanumeric0000', \
'000alphanumeric']
trailingremoved = []
leadingremoved = []
bothremoved = []

# Remove trailing
for i in listOfNum:
  while i[-1] == "0":
    i = i[:-1]
  trailingremoved.append(i)

# Remove leading
for i in listOfNum:
  while i[0] == "0":
    i = i[1:]
  leadingremoved.append(i)

# Remove both
for i in listOfNum:
  while i[0] == "0":
    i = i[1:]
  while i[-1] == "0":
    i = i[:-1]
  bothremoved.append(i)
```

Answer (score 372, accepted):

What about a basic

```
your_string.strip("0")
```

to remove both trailing and leading zeros ? If you're only interested in removing trailing zeros, use `.rstrip` instead (and `.lstrip` for only the leading ones).

More info in the [doc.](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.strip)

You could use some list comprehension to get the sequences you want like so:

```
trailing_removed = [s.rstrip("0") for s in listOfNum]
leading_removed = [s.lstrip("0") for s in listOfNum]
both_removed = [s.strip("0") for s in listOfNum]
```

Comment: Is there any clever adjustment for this answer for the special case of `s = '0'`?

Comment: @Charles : Yes! I just had the same problem, and you can do `s.strip("0") or "0"`: if your string turns into the empty string, it will evaluate as `False` by or and will be replaced by the desired string `"0"`

Comment: @Pierre GM Thank you . It really helps and it is very simple. Upvoted it

Answer (score 24):

Remove leading + trailing `'0'`:

```
list = [i.strip('0') for i in list_of_num]
```

Remove leading `'0'`:

```
list = [i.lstrip('0') for i in list_of_num]
```

Remove trailing `'0'`:

```py
list = [i.rstrip('0') for i in list_of_num]
```

Answer (score 9):

You can simply do this with a bool:

```py
if int(number) == float(number):   
    number = int(number)   
else:   
    number = float(number)
```

Comment: Doesn't work with `alphanumeric0000` as OP requested.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try with [strip()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) :

```
listOfNum = ['231512-n','1209123100000-n00000','alphanumeric0000', 'alphanumeric']
print [item.strip('0') for item in listOfNum]

>>> ['231512-n', '1209123100000-n', 'alphanumeric', 'alphanumeric']
```

Answer (score 4):

`pandas` also propose a convenient method :

```py
listOfNum = pd.Series(['000231512-n','1209123100000-n00000','alphanumeric0000', '000alphanumeric'])

listOfNum.str.strip("0")
listOfNum.str.ltrip("0")
listOfNum.str.rtrip("0")
```

The first one would give, for instance :

```
0           231512-n
1    1209123100000-n
2       alphanumeric
3       alphanumeric
dtype: object
```

This might be more convenient when working with `DataFrames`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have other data types (and not only string) in your list try this. This removes trailing and leading zeros from strings and leaves other data types untouched. This also handles the special case s = '0'

e.g

```
a = ['001', '200', 'akdl00', 200, 100, '0']

b = [(lambda x: x.strip('0') if isinstance(x,str) and len(x) != 1 else x)(x) for x in a]

b
>>>['1', '2', 'akdl', 200, 100, '0']
```

Answer (score 1):

`str.strip` is the best approach for this situation, but [`more_itertools.strip`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.strip) is also a general solution that strips both leading and trailing elements from an iterable:

**Code**

```
import more_itertools as mit


iterables = ["231512-n\n","  12091231000-n00000","alphanum0000", "00alphanum"]
pred = lambda x: x in {"0", "\n", " "}
list("".join(mit.strip(i, pred)) for i in iterables)
# ['231512-n', '12091231000-n', 'alphanum', 'alphanum']
```

---

**Details**

Notice, here we strip both leading and trailing `"0"`s among other elements that satisfy a predicate.  This tool is not limited to strings.

See also docs for more examples of

- [`more_itertools.strip`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.strip): strip both ends
- [`more_itertools.lstrip`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.lstrip): strip the left end
- [`more_itertools.rstrip`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.rstrip): strip the right end

[`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) is a third-party library installable via `> pip install more_itertools`.