# How to convert my hex address?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, llvmlite

I have the following hex number 0x00000000004087b8 and I have to convert this to 0x4087b8 so I would be able to append it to my list. Does anyone have  any Idea how can I do this conversion in python?

Comment: Could be [this kind of thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142347/how-to-remove-leading-and-trailing-zeros-in-a-string-python)

Comment: I would assume that wouldn't work since strip would remove the 0 before the x too. She'd have to split it first and then lstrip it instead.

Comment: what is "0x00000000004087b8 "?? A string?

Comment: You realize the two hex numbers in your questions have different values on a 64 bit machine? Is stripping away the prefix zero's to go to different architectures (e.g. 64 to 32 or...)?

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you have a string, I will recommend doing it like that :

```
fixed_address = hex(int(address, 16))
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this would work?

```
hex_num = "0x00000000004087b8"
hex_num = "0x{}".format(hex.split('x')[1].lstrip('0'))
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Forgot the quotes. My bad. Try now.