# Better way to remove trailing zeros from an integer

Tags: python, int

I'm an inexperienced programmer. I'm trying to remove trailing zeros from a whole number, an integer, for a project I've set myself in python.

I have managed to do this but there must be a better way than the monstrosity I have concocted!

```
def removeZeros(number):
    return int(str(int(str(number)[::-1]))[::-1])
```

Essentially I'm turning the integer into a string, reversing the string, turning it back into an integer---which removes the now leading zeros, turning it back into a string and reversing it; and finally turning it back into an integer to return it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may want to look into the differences between floats and integers, that may help you get in the right direction.

Comment: What about `int(str(number).strip("0"))`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove leading and trailing zeros in a string? Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142347/how-to-remove-leading-and-trailing-zeros-in-a-string-python)

Comment: are you sure that you want to remove trailing zero's from `integer`? not float?

Comment: @guidot thats the one, thanks.

Comment: @BladeMight I definitely need integer, I'm storing the results as integer in sqlite and will calculate the value in money in python. The trailing zeros are the result of a calculation but are not needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use [`str.rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip):

```
def remove_zeros(number):
    return int(str(number).rstrip('0'))
```

You could also do it without converting the number to a string, which should be slightly faster:

```
def remove_zeros(number):
    while number % 10 == 0:
        number //= 10
    return number
```

Comment: can you explain what is happening in your second example?

Comment: @sylph While the last digit of the number is `0` (checked with the [`%`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4432208/244297) operator) we discard it by dividing the number by 10.

Comment: Thanks I just worked it out. I keep forgetting you can do `x //= 10` instead of `x = x / 10`. Need to do more studying! Very elegant solution by the way and perfect for what I need, thanks.

Comment: Just a quick note about @EugeneYarmash's comment: the operator `%` doesn't check what the last digit of a number is. It just computes the remainder of a division ie. `13 % 10` gives you `3` because `13 / 10 = 1 remainder 3`. It's just that in base 10, if a number is divisible by 10 then it ends with a `0`.