# How to remove leading '0' from my column? Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove the '0' leading my data

My dataframe looks like this

```
Id    Year   Month    Day
1     2019   01       15
2     2019   03       30
3     2019   10       20
4     2019   11       18
```

Note: 'Year','Month','Day' columns data types are `object`

I get the 'Year','Month','Day' columns by extracting it from a date.
I want to remove the '0' at the beginning of each months.

**Desired Ouput:**

```
Id    Year   Month    Day
1     2019   1        15
2     2019   3        30
3     2019   10       20
4     2019   11       18
```

**What I tried to do so far:**
`df['Month'].str.lstrip('0')`

But it did not work.

Any solution? Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove leading and trailing zeros in a string? Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142347/how-to-remove-leading-and-trailing-zeros-in-a-string-python)

Comment: could you post a code example on how the dataframe is created?

Comment: If use `df['Month'].str.lstrip('0')` there is  error?

Comment: Same as jezrael, `df['Month'].str.lstrip('0')` works for me, so I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: `df['Month'] = df['Month'].astype(int)` or `df['Month'] = df['Month'].str.lstrip('0')`

Comment: There is no error message, but not changes are being made to my column

Comment: @KilliMandjaro You have to assign it back. `_.str.lstrip` is not inplace method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use re package and apply regex on it

```
import re
# Create sample data
d = pd.DataFrame(data={"Month":["01","02","03","10","11"]})
d["Month" = d["Month"].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r"^0+", "", x))
```

Result:

```
0     1
1     2
2     3
3    10
4    11
Name: Month, dtype: object
```

If you are 100% that Month column will always contain numbers, then you could simply do:

```
d["Month"] = d["Month"].astype(int)
```