# Remove leading zeros from python complex executable string

Tags: python, leading-zero

I am working with Grammatical Evolution (GE) on Python 3.7.
My grammar generates executable strings in the format:

```
np.where(<variable> <comparison_sign> <constant>, (<probability1>), (<probability2>))
```

Yet, the string can get quite complex, with several chained `np.where` .

`<constant>` in some cases contains leading zeros, which makes the executable string to generate errors. **GE is supposed to generate expressions containing leading zeros**, however, I have to **detect** and **remove** them.
An example of a possible solution containing leading zeros:

```
"np.where(x < 02, np.where(x > 01.5025, (0.9), (0.5)), (1))"
```

**Problem:**

- There are two types of numbers containing leading zeros: int and float.
- Supposing that I detect "02" in the string. If I replace all occurrences in the string from "02" to "2", the float "01.5025" will also be changed to "01.525", which cannot happen.

I've made several attempts with different `re` patterns, but couldn't solve it.
To detect that an executable string contains leading zeros, I use:

```
try:
  _ = eval(expression)
except SyntaxError:
  new_expression = fix_expressions(expression)
```

I need help building the `fix_expressions` Python function.

Comment: is this a solution for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142347/how-to-remove-leading-and-trailing-zeros-in-a-string-python ?

Comment: Partially. Two things missing: detect solely numbers with leading zeros and replace only those occurrences, without changing other numbers that contain them partially. Example: replacing "02" with "2" without changing "0.025" to "0.25".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to come up with a regular expression for numbers with leading zeros and then replace the leading zeros.

```py
import re

def remove_leading_zeros(string):
    return re.sub(r'([^\.^\d])0+(\d)', r'\1\2', string)

print(remove_leading_zeros("np.where(x < 02, np.where(x > 01.5025, (0.9), (0.5)), (1))"))

# output: np.where(x < 2, np.where(x > 1.5025, (0.9), (0.5)), (1))
```

The `remove_leading_zeros` function basically finds all occurrences of `[^\.^\d]0+\d` and removes the zeros. `[^\.^\d]0+\d` translates to not a number nor a dot followed by at least one zero followed by a number. The brackets `(`, `)` in the regex signalize [capture groups](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#grouping), which are used to preserve the character before the leading zeros and the number after.

---

Regarding [Csaba Toth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/292502/csaba-toth)'s comment:

The problem with `02+03*04` is that there is a zero at the beginning of the string.
One can [modify the regex](https://regex101.com/r/54wNwU/1) such that it matches also the beginning of the string in the first capture group:

```py
r"(^|[^\.^\d])0+(\d)"
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much :)

Comment: One thing this lacks is that it leaves a leading 0 in the string: `02+03*04` would become `02+3*4`.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove leading 0's in a string using `.lstrip()`

```
str_num = "02.02025"

print("Initial string: %s \n" % str_num)

str_num = str_num.lstrip("0")

print("Removing leading 0's with lstrip(): %s" % str_num)
```

Comment: This is applicable to cases where I have a string containing only numbers. Notice that my string expressions are more complex. Even if I can detect only numbers containing leading zeros, how can I replace them in the whole expression, without affecting other numbers? Example: replacing "02" with "2" without changing "0.025" to "0.25".

Comment: If your goal is to remove leading 0's lstrip() doesn't mind if the string is all numbers or both numbers and characters. if str_num was equal to 02.025 it will return 2.025

Comment: I tried:
"np.where(x < 02, np.where(x > 01.5025, (0.9), (0.5)), (1))".lstrip("0")
and i got:
"np.where(x < 02, np.where(x > 01.5025, (0.9), (0.5)), (1))"
So either I can't explain my problem, or I don't understand your suggestion...

Comment: the string that represents `<constant>` is what you would want to use the lstrip("0") function on. However, maybe I am misunderstanding what you're asking.

Comment: My problem is to detect only those occurrences in the whole string and replace only those ones. Example: I detect "02", apply ```lstrip()``` and replace it in the entire string with ```str.replace("02", "2")```. By doing this, the number "0.025" will also be replaced with "0.25", since "02" is a substring of "0.025". Right?

Comment: Copy the code I put above in my answer into a new file and run it and see the output results. I'm not sure what your code looks like so I am not sure how everything is structured. Maybe this won't help your circumstances

Comment: ```re.sub(r'([^\.^\d])0+(\d)', r'\1\2', string)``` this solved my problem. Thank you anyway!